# Match sum of values in array against number

Tags: php

I want to match different combinations of the values in an array with a specific number.

För example:

```
number = 10

Array (2, 6, 5, 3, 4)
```

Match will return : `6 + 4 = 10`, `2 + 3 + 5 = 10`

I could loop through all possible combinations but are there any faster or easier way to solve my problem?

Comment: There's no built-in function to do this, so you will need to loop.... the only thing you could do to reduce the looping is filter out any values from the array greater than your target number, though this doesn't apply in your example case

Comment: Thank you! Then I will try to optimize the array by removing unnecessary values.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a small issue with the answer, it returns all combination ie 2,3,5 and 3,2,5 etc..**

```
<?php

$array = array(2, 6, 5, 3, 4);

function depth_picker($arr, $temp_string, &$collect) {
    if ($temp_string != "") 
        $collect []= $temp_string;

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr);$i++) {
        $arrcopy = $arr;
        $elem = array_splice($arrcopy, $i, 1); // removes and returns the i'th element
        if (sizeof($arrcopy) > 0) {
            depth_picker($arrcopy, $temp_string ."," . $elem[0], $collect);
        } else {
            $collect []= $temp_string. "," . $elem[0];
        }   
    }   
}

$collect = array();
depth_picker($array, "", $collect);
foreach($collect as $val)
{
   $sum  = array_sum(explode(",",$val));
   if($sum == 10){
      print_r($val);
      echo "<br>";
   }
}

?>
```